# Check if a string is a base36 id?

Tags: python, base36

Assuming I have a function `base36-2check`,

And a user can input a string, how would I check that that string is base36?

Comment: Couldn't you just check it doesn't contain any non base36 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch the `int` constructor's exception, like so:

```
In [3]: try:
   ...:     int('abc!d', 36)
   ...: except ValueError:
   ...:     print "Nope"
```

Sample program:

```
def base36_check(s):
    try:
        int(s, 36)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


print base36_check('abcdefg')
print base36_check('abc!efg')
```